# Flink : Rowtime attributes must not be in the input rows of a regular join

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-sql

Using flink SQL API, I want to join multiple tables together and do some computation over time window.
I have 3 table coming from CSV files, and one coming from Kafka.
In the Kafka table, I have a field `timestampMs`, that I want to use for my time window operations.

For that I did the following code :

```
reamExecutionEnvironment env = ... ;
StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

TableSource table1 = CsvTableSource.builder()
        .path("path/to/file1.csv")
        .ignoreFirstLine()
        .fieldDelimiter(",")
        .field("id1", Types.STRING)
        .field("someInfo1", Types.FLOAT)
        .build();

TableSource table2 = CsvTableSource.builder()
        .path("path/to/file2.csv")
        .ignoreFirstLine()
        .fieldDelimiter(",")
        .field("id2", Types.STRING)
        .field("someInfo2", Types.STRING)
        .build();

TableSource table3 = CsvTableSource.builder()
        .path("path/to/file3.csv")
        .ignoreFirstLine()
        .fieldDelimiter(",")
        .field("id2", Types.STRING)
        .field("id1", Types.STRING)
        .field("someInfo3", Types.FLOAT)
        .build();

tableEnv.registerTableSource("Table1",table1);
tableEnv.registerTableSource("Table2",table2);
tableEnv.registerTableSource("Table3",table3);


Schema schemaExt = new Schema().schema(SOME_SCHEMA);
schemaExt = schemaExt.field("rowtime", Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP).rowtime(new Rowtime().timestampsFromField("timestampMs").watermarksPeriodicBounded(40000));

tableEnv.connect(new Kafka()
        .version("universal")
        .topic(MY_TOPIC)
        .properties(MY_PROPERTIES)
        .sinkPartitionerRoundRobin()
)
            .withFormat(...)
            .withSchema(schemaExt)
            .inAppendMode()
            .registerTableSource("KafkaInput");

Table joined = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM table1 " +
        "join table3 on table1.id2 = table3.id2 " +
        "join table2 on table3.id1 = table2.id1 " +
        "join KafkaInput on table3.id2 = KafkaInput.id2");

tableEnv.registerTable("Joined", joined);

int windowWidth = 5;
int frequency = 2;
Table processed = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT id1 FROM Joined " +
        "GROUP BY id1, HOP(rowtime, INTERVAL '10' SECOND, INTERVAL '30' SECOND)");



Sink s = createSink(this.esEndpoint, this.esPattern, this.schemaHandler.getSchemaStr());


tableEnv.registerTableSink("MySink", ...);

processed.insertInto("MySink");

env.execute();
```

But when I run it, I have the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Cannot generate a valid execution plan for the given query: 
Rowtime attributes must not be in the input rows of a regular join. As a workaround you can cast the time attributes of input tables to TIMESTAMP before.
```

But I don't understand the workaround tip part. How can I create a time attribute and do some windowed computation after joining my tables.

--- EDIT ---

In the above code, I replaced the following lines :

```
Table joined = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM table1 " +
        "join table3 on table1.id2 = table3.id2 " +
        "join table2 on table3.id1 = table2.id1 " +
        "join KafkaInput on table3.id2 = KafkaInput.id2");

tableEnv.registerTable("Joined", joined);
```

By :

```
Table staticJoined = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT *, TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00') as rowtime FROM table1 " +
        "join table3 on table1.id2 = table3.id2 " +
        "join table2 on table3.id1 = table2.id1 ");

TemporalTableFunction temporalFunction = staticJoined.createTemporalTableFunction( "rowtime" , "id2");
tableEnv.registerFunction("CSVData", temporalFunction);

tableEnv.registerTable("Joined",
    tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM KafkaInput, LATERAL TABLE (CSVData(KafkaInput.rowtime)) as Statics WHERE Statics.id2 = KafkaInput.id2")
);
```

But I get an error with the TemporalTableFunction :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Cannot add expression of different type to set:
set type is RecordType(BIGINT genTimestampMs, BIGINT timestampMs, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" streamId, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" sdkConfId, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" sdkId, FLOAT density, FLOAT count, FLOAT surface, TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL rowtime, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" streamId0, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" cameraName, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" streamId00, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" areaId, FLOAT coefficient, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" areaId0, FLOAT thresholdLow, FLOAT thresholdMedium, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" areaId1, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" name, TIMESTAMP(3) rowtime0, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" StationName) NOT NULL
expression type is RecordType(BIGINT genTimestampMs, BIGINT timestampMs, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" streamId, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" sdkConfId, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" sdkId, FLOAT density, FLOAT count, FLOAT surface, TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL rowtime, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" streamId0, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" cameraName, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" streamId00, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" areaId, FLOAT coefficient, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" areaId0, FLOAT thresholdLow, FLOAT thresholdMedium, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" areaId1, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" name, TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL rowtime0, VARCHAR(65536) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16LE" COLLATE "ISO-8859-1$en_US$primary" StationName) NOT NULL
set is rel#26:LogicalCorrelate.NONE(left=HepRelVertex#24,right=HepRelVertex#25,correlation=$cor0,joinType=inner,requiredColumns={8})
expression is LogicalTemporalTableJoin#32
```

Where two fields do not match between the 'set type' and the 'expression type'.
`TIMESTAMP(3) rowtime0` and `TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL rowtime0`

The problem is that I have no field named `rowtime0`. It look like it is an internal field. I don't really understand what's happening here

Answer (score 6):

Your query defines regular joins, i.e., joins without a temporal join constraint. Since Flink treats all tables as dynamic (i.e., assumes that they might change in the future), a regular join without time constraints cannot guarantee that rows are emitted (roughly) in timestamp order. However, timestamp order is required for time attributes to ensure that subsequent operations (such as window aggregations) can be preformed without fully materializing the stream. Therefore, Flink does not allow time attributes as input (and hence also output) of a regular join that does not preserve the time order.

The problem would not exist, if Flink would be aware that the tables from the CSV files are fixed and not dynamic. However, this reasoning is not yet supported.

As a workaround, you can model the CSV tables as [temporal tables](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/table/streaming/temporal_tables.html) (that are not changing) and [join them](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#join-with-a-temporal-table) with the Kafka table.

Comment: Thanks! I am not really sure of how to model my CSV tables as temporal tables though.

Comment: You register them as regular tables (as you already did) and then register a temporal table function on such a table as explained [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/table/streaming/temporal_tables.html#defining-temporal-table-function). Once the temporal table function is defined, you can use it to join the stream with the temporal (CSV) table.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I do not succeed to create TemporalTableFunction as describe in your link. I edited the post.

Comment: @FabianHueske please can you take a look at [my similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64445207/rowtime-attributes-must-not-be-in-the-input-rows-of-a-regular-join-despite-usi)? I specified a temporal join constraint but it doesn't seem to help.