# Flink Autojoin with rowtime column

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a Flink table with the following structure :

```
Id1, Id2, myTimestamp, value
```

Where the rowtime is based on `myTimestamp`.

I have the following processing that works well :

```
Table processed = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT " +
                "Id1, " +
                "MAX(myTimestamp) as myTimestamp, " +
                "SUM(value) as value " +
                "FROM MyTable " +
                "GROUP BY Id1, HOP(rowtime, INTERVAL 10 SECOND, INTERVAL 30 SECOND)");
```

I want to adapt the previous code, such as for each window, I use only the latest record per `Id2`. So I though that changing the code as follow would work :

```
Table processed = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT " +
                "Id1, " +
                "MAX(myTimestamp) as myTimestamp, " +
                "SUM(value) as value " +
                "FROM MyTable, " + 
                "(SELECT Id2, MAX(myTimestamp) as latestTimestamp FROM MyTable GROUP BY Id2) as RecordsLatest" +
                "WHERE  MyTable.Id2 = RecordsLatest.Id2 AND MyTable.myTimestamp = RecordsLatest.myTimestamp" +
                "GROUP BY Id1, HOP(rowtime, INTERVAL 10 SECOND, INTERVAL 30 SECOND)");
```

But when I do so, I get the following error :

```
Rowtime attributes must not be in the input rows of a regular join. As a workaround you can cast the time attributes of input tables to TIMESTAMP before.
Please check the documentation for the set of currently supported SQL features.
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.runVolcanoPlanner(TableEnvironment.scala:387)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.optimizePhysicalPlan(TableEnvironment.scala:302)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.StreamTableEnvironment.optimize(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:816)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.StreamTableEnvironment.writeToSink(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:351)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.insertInto(TableEnvironment.scala:879)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.Table.insertInto(table.scala:1126)
```

It looks like Flink do not 'understand' that the two tables I am joining are the same one.

How can I do what I want to do ?

Comment: possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57181771/flink-rowtime-attributes-must-not-be-in-the-input-rows-of-a-regular-join

Comment: Well, actually it was also my question and it is not about the same thing. On the first question, my data were static, and i was able to bypass the probleme using a TableFunction. But in my case, my data are dynamic, so I can't use this solution, and no other working solution were given.

Comment: Did you try this approach https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/dynamic_tables.html#dynamic-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few reasons why your query does not work.

```sql
SELECT 
  Id1, MAX(myTimestamp) as myTimestamp, SUM(value) as value 
FROM 
  MyTable, 
  (SELECT Id2, MAX(myTimestamp) as latestTimestamp 
   FROM MyTable 
   GROUP BY Id2
  ) as RecordsLatest
WHERE 
  MyTable.Id2 = RecordsLatest.Id2 
  AND MyTable.myTimestamp = RecordsLatest.myTimestamp
GROUP BY 
  Id1, HOP(rowtime, INTERVAL 10 SECOND, INTERVAL 30 SECOND)
```

Some are due to limitations in Flink, others are more fundamental.

1. `latestTimestamp` is not a rowtime attribute anymore. This is because, it is computed. As soon as you use a rowtime attribute in an expression (incl. aggregation functions like `MAX`) they lose their rowtime property and become regular `TIMESTAMP` attributes.
2. The inner query produces a dynamic table that updates its results. It is not an append-only table. As soon as the max timestamp of an `Id2` changes, the previous result row needs to be retracted and the new result row be inserted.
3. Since `RecordsLatest` is an updating table (and not an append-only table) and `latestTimestamp` is not a rowtime attribute, the join of `RecordsLatest` and `MyTable` is a "regular join" (and not a time-windowed join) that produces also an updating result and not an append-only result. A regular join cannot produce any rowtime attributes, because there is no guarantee about the order of output rows (which is a prerequisite for rowtime attributes because they need to be aligned with watermarks) and results might need to remove them in the future. This is causing the error message that you see.
4. The `GROUP BY` clause of the outer query requires an append-only input table with a rowtime attribute `rowtime`. However, the output of the join is not append-only but updating and the `rowtime` attribute cannot be a rowtime attribute as explained before.

Solving your task is unfortunately not straightforward but should be possible.

First of all, you should return have a query that returns for each (`Id1, Id2`) window the values for row with the max timestamp:

```sql
SELECT 
  Id1, Id2,
  MAX(myTimestamp) AS maxT
  ValOfMaxT(valX, myTimestamp) AS valXOfMaxT,
  HOP_ROWTIME(myTimestamp, INTERVAL '10' SECOND, INTERVAL '30' SECOND) AS rowtime
FROM
  MyTable
GROUP BY
  Id1, Id2, HOP(myTimestamp, INTERVAL '10' SECOND, INTERVAL '30' SECOND)
```

The `ValOfMaxT` function is a user-defined aggregation function that identifies the value for the maximum timestamp and returns it. `rowtime` is the new rowtime attribute and 1ms before the end timestamp of the window.

Given this table, let's call it `Temp` you can define the next query as:

```sql
SELECT
  Id1, MAX(maxT) as myTimestamp, SUM(valXOfMaxT)
FROM Temp
GROUP BY
  Id1, TUMBLE(rowtime, INTERVAL '10' SECONDS)
```

This query only groups on `Id1` and a `TUMBLE` window. It's a `TUMBLE` window because the first `HOP` window already grouped each record into three windows and we should not do that again. Instead, we group the result of the first query into 10 second windows, because that's the slide length of the `HOP` windows in the first query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
My original code is doing some aggregation over time window and the field `Id1`
In the modified code, I want to keep for each `Id2` only the record with the highest `myTimestamp` value, and then apply the original aggregation over `Id1` and time window.
I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Hmm, so within each window you only want to have the record with the highest `myTimestamp` and "aggregate" over a single record?

Comment: Not exactly. There is two distinct keys. The key `Id2`, for which I want only the record with the highest `myTimestamp`, and then, group all these 'latest `Id2`' by key `Id1`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks !